# BOOTSTRAP Sign in template not working on FORM

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, forms

My login page isn't looking like the way I want it to which is like this bootstrap signin page right here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/. This is [what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPLgT.jpg)

If you can help me out with this, it would mean **the world to me**.

Also if you think it's because I didn't link to a CSS page here's what my base template looks like and my structure:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Accounts</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/signin.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            {% block main_content %} 
            {% endblock %} 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
      authenticate,
      get_user_model,
      login,
      logout,
 )
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UserLoginForm

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)      
        if user is not None:
          login(request, user)
          # or any other success page
        #   return HttpResponse("Logged in")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/home')
    return render(request, "accounts/form.html", {"form":form, "title": title})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,

    )

User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput) 

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

    def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect Password")
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active.")
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
```

form.html (currently using this for login, open to use the same format for registration)

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' value='{{ title }}' />
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[What My Framework Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1kNv.jpg)

Thanks a lot

@Lemayzeur this is [what my site looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gF2Z.jpg)

And this is [what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yczD.jpg)

-it comes pretty close but unfortunately it's not the same. Nonetheless, I'll keep it and thank you.

Comment: It's because your inputs don't have the `bootstrap class`

Comment: @Lemayzeur thanks a lot for your feedback, but can you please be more specific? What inputs are you talking about specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file works well because the button inherits the bootstrap design,
the problem is all the inputs that you have don't have the class `form-control`. So to add these classes, you can do it with the widget

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=120,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',"placeholder":"Username"}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
          widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',"placeholder":"Password"}))
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your help. I've taken your suggestion and put it into action. Unfortunately, I'm sorry to say that it didn't achieve the look I was going for. At the very bottom of my question, I've attached the images of how my site looks now vs the bootstrap template that I want it to look like. However, since this is still better than what I originally had, I'm going to keep it, so thank you.

Comment: The design that you see is not a bootstrap property at all. It's just because of more css `signin.css` in the project, for instance, I copied [the file `signin.css`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css) from the above bootstrap link. you can take a look